# how to make input not case sensitive

Tags: python

so i recently started my coding journey and am a freshman computer science student and i decided to do a side project where i input a country and it tells me the continent uknow for fun, although when i write the input it dosnt work and i think it has to do with it being case sensitive. pls help

here's the code i currently made

```
country = input('Tell me a country... ')

# all the countries in africa

countries_in_africa = ["Sao Tome and Principe", "senegal",
                       "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South africa", "South Sudan", ]

if country.upper() in countries_in_africa:
    print('country is in africa')

else:
    print('country is not in africa')
```

Comment: Convert the input to all lowercase with `country = input('...').lower()`, and make sure the names in your list are also in lowercase.

Comment: Your code doesn't work as posted because you're converting the input to uppercase, but the country names in the list are not in uppercase.

Comment: Take a look at the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) that deal with case.

Comment: `country.upper()` make all letters in string upper. E.g. `'cat'.upper()` will become 'CAT'. Is it what you wanted from this code?

Answer (score 0):

When you write the following

```py
if country.upper() in countries_in_africa:
    print('country is in africa')
```

You're searching for an all-caps string. Casing is important as you've noted. To get around it you can also convert all strings in `countries_in_africa` to uppercase.

Either do it manually when you define the list, or on the fly

```py
if country.upper() in list(map(str.upper, countries_in_africa)):
    print('country is in africa')
```